# Generate a Random Color Java

Tags: java, android, random, colors

I am trying to create a random color by randomly generating numbers for R,G, and B values with a random number generator, and using the values to make a color. The following code is in my `onCreate()` method:

```
Random rand = new Random();
    // Java 'Color' class takes 3 floats, from 0 to 1.
    float r = rand.nextFloat();
    float g = rand.nextFloat();
    float b = rand.nextFloat();
    Color randomColor = new Color(r, g, b);
```

How come eclipse tells me "The constructor `Color(float, float, float)` is undefined"? Shouldn't this work correctly?

Comment: Have you correctly imported it?

Comment: Make sure you're declaring "java.awt.Color": http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html.  "android.graphics.Color", on the other hand, does NOT have a constructor with float rgb: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#rgb%28int

Comment: Seems like eclipse auto-imported "android.graphics.Color". I made it import "java.awt.Color" and it is now working. Thank you

Comment: @ThatGuyThere coding for android right?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should use [nextInt(int n):int](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) to generate a random integer between 0 and 255. *(note that according to API the range is not checked within the Color methods so if you don't limit it yourself you'll end up with invalid color values)*

```
// generate the random integers for r, g and b value
Random rand = new Random();
int r = rand.nextInt(255);
int g = rand.nextInt(255);
int b = rand.nextInt(255);
```

Then get an int color value with the static [Color.rgb(r,g,b):int](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#rgb%28int,%20int,%20int%29) method. The only constructor that exists for `android.graphics.Color` is a non argument constructor.

```
int randomColor = Color.rgb(r,g,b);
```

Finally, as an example, use the [setBackgroundColor(int c):void](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29) method to set a color background to a view.

```
View someView.setBackgroundColor(randomColor);
```

Comment: `public static int rgb` return type is `int`

Comment: indeed fixed that and added some more info on how to use the int color value to set background color to view for instance.

Comment: the post looks more complete now.

Comment: It should be rand.nextInt(256). nextInt "returns a pseudo-random uniformly distributed int in the half-open range [0, n)."

Comment: 1 line code: 
        `view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255)));`

Comment: @Prabs One line of code isn't always better, especially when showing examples I would vote against the single line notation.

Comment: @hcpl I feel it's a good practice, because we aren't allocating memory to variables which we will use only once. It might not be good for explanation but it is good for usage. Don't you think so?

Answer (score 3):

```
public int randomColor(int alpha) {

    int r = (int) (0xff * Math.random());
    int g = (int) (0xff * Math.random());
    int b = (int) (0xff * Math.random());

    return Color.argb(alpha, r, g, b);
}
```

can it help?

Answer (score 3):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

`Color()`

Constructor does not take any params

Use

`public static int rgb (int red, int green, int blue)`

Return a color-int from red, green, blue components. The alpha component is implicity 255 (fully opaque). These component values should be [0..255], but there is no range check performed, so if they are out of range, the returned color is undefined.

Parameters
red Red component [0..255] of the color
green   Green component [0..255] of the color
blue    Blue component [0..255] of the color

Use

```
Random rand = new Random();
int r = rand.nextInt(255);
...// rest of the code  
int randomcolor = Color.rgb(r,g,b); // takes int as param
```

Answer (score 1):

Makeuse of **Color.rgb()** method

```
Color.rgb((randval)r,(randval)g,(randval)b);
```

to generate random color.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was actually with my imports, but this is a great approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

If The constructor Color(float, float, float) is undefined than convert it into int like.

```
Random rand = new Random();
// Java 'Color' class takes 3 floats, from 0 to 1.
float r = rand.nextFloat();
float g = rand.nextFloat();
float b = rand.nextFloat();
int Red = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(r));
int Green= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(g));
int Blue= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(b));
Color randomColor = new Color(Red , Green, Blue);
```

But Don't know that it works or not if doesn't work then try this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int r = rand.nextInt(255);
int g = rand.nextInt(255);
int b = rand.nextInt(255);
Color randomColor = new Color(r, g, b);
```

It should works but if it doesn't works then comment.